# How to set deeper patterns in arguments within function definitions. For example if an argument must be a list of 1 or more strings

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, pattern-matching, string-manipulation, argument-patterns

Suppose I want to define a function whose argument must be a List of only Strings and List must have at least one member. I know how to require that the Head must be a List but how does one qualify List members within an argument? I really don't want to resort pattern matching inside the body of my definitions or trailing a conditional pattern outside my definitions.

This is what I have so far along with a few test cases...

```
fn[arg_List && AllTrue[arg, StringQ] && Length@arg > 0] := 
  Block[{}, arg];
fn[{"a", "b", "c"}] (* should return {"a","b","c"} *)
fn[{1, "b", "c"}]
fn[{}]
```

Unfortunately it produces no errors which in this case would have been very helpful.

Comment: does it work if you replace it with `fn[arg_List /; (AllTrue[arg, StringQ] && Length@arg > 0)] := Module[{}, arg];` ? btw, why Block there? Why not use normal `Module`?

Comment: @Nasser thank you that worked!!! i try not to use modules unless absolutely necessary because they require more memory and are slower than blocks.

Comment: `because they require more memory and are slower than blocks` I did not know this.  I use Modules all the time, since Block scoping is a little confusing to me. But if they work for you, that should work then.

Comment: You could also do `fn[arg_ /; VectorQ[arg, StringQ] && arg != {}] := ...`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When imposing restrictions on patterns, there are typically two options:

- Use [`Condition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) (`/;`) to specify an arbitrary expression as test. (This is what was shown in the comments)

  ```
  fn[arg_List /; (AllTrue[arg, StringQ] && Length@arg > 0)] := Module[{}, arg];
  fn[arg_ /; VectorQ[arg, StringQ] && arg != {}] := Module[{}, arg];
  ```

  This is most flexible, but can be significantly slower, since the pattern matcher has to ask the kernel to evaluate the condition
- Use structural patterns: The pattern `arg_List` is mostly equivalent to `arg:{___}`, where [`Pattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html) (`:`) gives the name, and the `{___}` is "anything that looks like a list with zero or more arguments (see [`BlankNullSequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankNullSequence.html), `___`). To require at least one element, use [`BlankSequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankSequence.html) (`__`). You can also specify a head for these elements, e.g. `__String`. So the pattern here would be:

  ```
  fn[arg:{__String}] := Module[{}, arg];
  ```

  If each element should follow a more complex pattern, you can use [`Repeated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Repeated.html) (`..`) and [`RepeatedNull`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RepeatedNull.html) (`...`). So to require e.g. a list of lists of strings, use

  ```
  fn[arg:{{__String}...}] := Module[{}, arg];
  ```

  If the condition on the single elements is more complex, you can use [`PatternTest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html) (`?`):

  ```
  fn[arg:{__String?(StringStartsQ["a"])}] := Module[{}, arg];
  ```

  This example requires a list of strings starting with `a`.

Comment: you really kicked ass on this answer. you dispel many mysteries behind conditional patterns for arguments that should have been better explained in the official documentation.

Comment: if i wanted this `fn[arg:{__String}] ` but wanted to require all strings have `StringLength > 0` not sure how to add that.

Comment: @JulesManson I would do it similar to the last example, so e.g. `(StringLength[#]>0&)` instead of `(StringContainsQ["a"])`